# convert IEnumerable<WebSocketHandler> to WebSocketCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket

I am using `Microsoft.Web.WebSockets` for an app.

I have a collection of users `WebSocketCollection group;` and i need to send message to everyone except one

```
 group.Except(group.Where(r=>((MicrosoftWebSockets)r).user_id==1)).Broadcast("Message");
```

But the moment i use Except clause `WebSocketCollection` becomes `IEnumerable<WebSocketHandler>` and then i cant use Broadcast method.

Any other approach would be helpful.

Comment: will this work `((WebSocketCollection)group.Except(group.Where(r=>((MicrosoftWebSockets)r).user_id==1))).Broadcast("Message")`

Comment: i get this error while casting Unable to cast object of type '<ExceptIterator>d__72`1[Microsoft.Web.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler]' to type 'Microsoft.Web.WebSockets.WebSocketCollection'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Broadcast` method is defined on the `WebSocketCollection` class. When you apply a LINQ query on `WebSocketCollection` you get a `IEnumerable<WebSocketHandler>` which does not have a `Broadcast` method.

You can create a new `WebSocketCollection` and then add the individual items using the `Add` method like this:

```
var handlers = group.Except(group.Where(r=>((MicrosoftWebSockets)r).user_id==1));

var collection = new WebSocketCollection();

foreach(var item in handlers)
{
    collection.Add(item);
}

collection.Broadcast("Message");
```

You could wrap this logic into an extension method like this:

```
public static class ExtentionMethods
{
    public static WebSocketCollection ToCollection(this IEnumerable<WebSocketHandler> handlers)
    {
        var collection = new WebSocketCollection();

        foreach (var item in handlers)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }

        return collection;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
group.Except(group.Where(r=>((MicrosoftWebSockets)r).user_id==1))
.ToCollection()
.Broadcast("Message");
```

By the way, your LINQ query can be done in a better way by negating the condition like this:

```
group.Where(r=> !(((MicrosoftWebSockets)r).user_id == 1))
.ToCollection()
.Broadcast("Message");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i did think of iterating the elements but wont it impact performance when iterating in large groups every time the event is being triggered

Comment: You should measure the performance impact. Most probably it is going to be neglectable.

Comment: so instead of making them a WebSocketCollection i can also just Send message individually in the loop itself?

Comment: Yes. That is an option too.